# Jenkins can't find directory when executing shell command

Tags: jenkins

I want to execute these shell command in my Jenkins job.

```
cd /Users/username/Desktop/JenkinsProject 
javac Jenkins.java
java Jenkins
```

However when I try to build I get the error:

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/JenkinsExample
[JenkinsExample] $ /bin/sh -xe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2459427386874444762.sh
+ cd /Users/username/Desktop/JenkinsProject
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2459427386874444762.sh: line 2: cd: /Users/username/Desktop/JenkinsProject: Not a directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Gitcolony notification failed - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid url: 
Finished: FAILURE
```

It looks like it can't find the folder when running the commands with Jenkins?
If I dont use Jenkins but run the commands in my terminal everything works fine.

Comment: Is Jenkins running the script on the correct slave?

Comment: @DibakarAditya not sure what you mean by slave? This is my first time trying to use Jenkins, so I might not understand even the simple Jenkins practices.

Comment: Ok, in practice Jenkins is mostly used as a master-slave set up where the machine on which you have installed Jenkins is the master. There could be n number of machines (slaves) connected to the master via SSH or JNLP, etc. to run the jobs. The idea is to let the master manage and distribute the workloads between the slaves, rather than running the jobs on itself, though that is possible too. So, may be the job is running on one of the slaves that doesn’t have the directories that you need.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for such a detailed answer. i apreciate it! I dont recall setting any other machines using SSH or JNLP, however I Will look and check for it as soon as I get home to my computer. I’m not sure where I Can check for these slaves in Jenkins but I guess I should be able to google myself to it and figure it out.

Comment: @DibakarAditya I checked and I'm running it on the master (my own computer), so it should have the folder available?

Comment: @DibakarAditya I tried to move the folder into my Jenkins/Home/workspace and now it allows to run my cd command. However I now get a permission error:
Jenkins.java:1: error: error while writing Jenkins: Jenkins.class (Permission denied)

Comment: Ok, grant appropriate permissions/ownership (SYSTEM user) to the directory that you moved.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out.